# How do you implement bubble sort on a vector of type class?

Tags: c++, c++11, bubble-sort

```
    do {
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (strs[i].compareTo(strs[i + 1]) > strs[i + 1].compareTo(strs[i])) {
            //swap(strs[i], strs[i + 1]);
            vector<ASString> temp;
            temp[0] = strs[i];
            strs[i] = strs[i + 1];
            strs[i + 1] = temp[0];
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
} while (swapped == true);
```

I have this but it throws errors saying that there was a "Invalid parameter was padded to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal"

Comment: Look up `std::swap`

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with `std::vector`.  If you had a regular array of Widgets, how in the world would subtracting one from the other swap them?

Comment: what errors does it throw?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, as long as he doesn't suffer from overflow, his swap logic is fine.

Comment: @AlexS, your code looks okay.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: @SidS -- How can the swap logic be "fine" if the type doesn't support `operator -`?  His code only works for integers -- it isn't even guaranteed to work for floating point types.

Comment: @Paul, how do you know what his container contains ?

Comment: @SidS -- I read between the lines.  His post mentions *I have this but it throws errors and I think it is for a string*.  Second, whatever you can do with arrays, you can do with vector with the same exact syntax.  Thus his issue has absolutely nothing to do with vector -- a plain old array would have the same issue he is seeing.

Comment: @Paul, I think I understand what you meant now.  And I still think a [mcve] is necessary.

Comment: Never use such first-appealing tricks to swap...

Comment: @vu1p3n0x invalid parameter was padded to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Comment: not certain about that error... but you've definitely got a problem at `vector<...> temp; temp[0] = ...` because `temp` does not have a first element you can assign to (its empty by default). Try swapping out the vector with `ASString temp = ` and go from there.

Comment: What does the `compareTo` function return? Normally, I would expect it to return a value indicating whether the object calling it and the object passed as argument are equal, less than or greater than each other. If that is the case why is it called on both sides of `<` operator. Also, why not use `ASString`'s object instead of using `vector<ASString>`. Another thing is that no memory has been allocated to that `vector`. You need to do `push_back` in `vector` to insert the first element since you have not initialized/allocated the vector using its constructor.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa 
Ostr < Astr returns a negative number
Ostr > Astr returns a positive number
Ostr == Astr returns zero

Just like the real compareTo function